# Using ubuntu header lib in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building an open source lib C/C++ for Android development using Android NDK. I had got code from Github and created my own jni folder under source code. In that jni folder, I created some C source files and included many header files in open source lib. But when I built, I had got failed log:

fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory

I checked and saw that file "libc-header-start.h" existed in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/ folder of Ubuntu system but when building, it can not link to that header file

**So can I use Ubuntu system header file in my Android NDK lib?**

Comment: Add `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` to your `cFlags` (assuming that this header is ok to use for Android.. Android has its own libc implementation after all).

Comment: Don't do that. Android does not use glibc and the two do not have compatible headers.

Comment: so what should I do to build a c/c++ library for android in Ubuntu OS? thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use Ubuntu (or any other host) includes or libs to build an Android NDK library. NDK cross-compiles your code for the Android targets. Not all C++ projects on GitHub may be ported easily to Android. If they use CMake, these scripts often need adaptations for Android NDK. If they use automake tools, tuning the build scripts may be quite painful.

Comment: I am compiling Coturn for android, can I do it ? :(

Answer (score 1):

> So can I use Ubuntu system header file in my Android NDK lib?

NO. You have to use all the Android NDK specific headers and libs for your NDK compilation, i.e. those inside your NDK folders.

Here is an example for Android JNI programming: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample

Comment: I need compiling Coturn into an Android lib for my project, but Coturn contain many include Ubuntu header file, so what should I do next :((

Comment: I am not sure this project can be ported to Android flawlessly. But you can give it a try by using NDK headers and libs. If some of the headers or libs don't exist inside NDK, probably you will fail to compile it on Android. Or you can look into the source code and try to find the counter components in NDK, but if you really run into such a situation, I don't think it is a trivial job.